# How to predict a winner in a 5v5 game using tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have data from a 5v5 player game that looks like this:

`map1,ally1,ally2,ally3,ally4,ally5,enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4,enemy5,winner`

For example:

`Jaguar Falls,Androxus,Tiberius,Khan,Jenos,Seris,Inara,Viktor,Terminus,Io,Tyra,1`

Jaguar Falls is the map the match took place on. Androxus,Tiberius,Khan,ect. are all types of champions you can select in the game. The last column being 1 indicates that the allied team won the game.

I have about 750 games worth of relevant data and another 7250 games worth of less relevant data that would still be better than nothing if needed. I'm trying to predict which team will win before the game has started.

This is how I read in the data:

```
field_names = ["map", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "result"]
df_train = pd.read_csv('input/match_results.csv', names=field_names, skiprows=1)
for count in range(1, 6):
    str_count = str(count)
    df_train['c' + str_count] = pd.Categorical(df_train['c' + str_count])
    df_train['c' + str_count] = eval("df_train.c" + str_count + ".cat.codes")
    df_train['e' + str_count] = pd.Categorical(df_train['e' + str_count])
    df_train['e' + str_count] = eval("df_train.e" + str_count + ".cat.codes")

    df_train['map'] = pd.Categorical(df_train['map'])
    df_train['map'] = df_train.map.cat.codes
    df_train['result'] = pd.Categorical(df_train['result'])
    # df_train['result']=pd.Float64Index
    df_train['result'] = df_train.result.cat.codes
target = df_train.pop('result')
targets = np.array(list(x for x in target.values))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_train.values, targets))
train_data = dataset.shuffle(len(df_train)).batch(1)
```

When I try to train a model on this data it never really seems to make progress in predicting the winner column and output looks something like this:

```
step: 7850, loss: nan, accuracy: 0.000000
step: 7900, loss: nan, accuracy: 1.000000
step: 7950, loss: nan, accuracy: 1.000000
step: 8000, loss: nan, accuracy: 0.000000
step: 8050, loss: nan, accuracy: 1.000000
step: 8100, loss: nan, accuracy: 0.000000
step: 8150, loss: nan, accuracy: 1.000000
step: 8200, loss: nan, accuracy: 0.000000
```

Just a couple question so far:

1. How can my accuracy always be 0 or 1? Shouldn't it be some percentage or decimal between 0 and 1?
2. Is the way I'm reading in the data correct for at least a naive approach to this problem?

I'm also aware that I probably don't have enough data to train my model this way, so I was [reading about teaching the AI about team compositions](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/hero2vec-d42d6838c941). I even converted [this repository](https://github.com/ybw9000/hero2vec) to work with the game I have data for and now have a champion model file named model.p that based on the visualizations it generates seems to have learned the different roles that each champion fills on a team.

Now for more questions:

1. The person who wrote [this article](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/hero2vec-d42d6838c941) doesn't explain the whole process, so I'm not sure how to leverage the champion model.p file I have to improve my win rate prediction. Is there a way to tell tensorflow that c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 and e1,e2,e3,e4,e5 are all champions and give it this model to better understand how these champions relate? My understanding is I can use the model to encode similar champions in a similar way before passing them to tensorflow.

Comment: I notice that you have `.batch(1)`, which would produce a batch size of 1, and is likely why your accuracy was exactly 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks @duckboycool that did fix the accuracy. Do you have any advice on choosing a batch size?

Comment: If you're going with the dataset of 750, then probably a small batch size like 8 or 16, but you could try different things to see what works best.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of datasets and also changed it to loop over the dataset multiple times (it was going over once and then stopping). I'm able to get it training for longer but my loss starts at 89 and then quickly goes up to infinity...doesn't seem like a good sign and not sure why it's happening. I've been playing around with params like number of neurons, batch size, etc. but no luck so far. I'm using the larger dataset until I can find an answer to my last question in the OP.